# Assigning values to df col by col not working

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to assign values in the following fashion:

```
    cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    df['A'] = '1' 
    df['B'] = '2' 
    df['C'] = '3'
```

but `df` seems empty:

```
 print(df.values)

>>> []
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is specified index in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df.loc[0, 'A'] = '1' 
df.loc[0, 'B'] = '2' 
df.loc[0, 'C'] = '3'

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
```

Or specified index in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=[0])

df['A'] = '1' 
df['B'] = '2' 
df['C'] = '3'
```